# Редирект 301 для внешней ссылки на Joomla сайте

Tags: редирект, joomla

Всем доброго времени суток!

Помогите разобраться. Есть сайт на joomla 1.5.22 на сайте установлен virtuemart (компонент электронного магазина), программисты, которые создавали магазин, не смогли реализовать нормальный фильтр по производителю товара, поэтому были созданы несколько ссылок (в joomla этот тип ссылок называется "Внешняя ссылка" ), примерно такого вида `/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=9`, так вот сейчас каталог изменился и необходимо сделать редирект с этих ссылок (типа внешних) на обычные ссылки на категории virtuemart, примерно такого вида: `/component/virtuemart/25-`.

Попробовал решить проблему с помощью компонента joomSEF, в нём есть менеджер редиректов, прописал туда старую ссылку и новую (куда нужно редиректнуть), т.е. (`/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=9` и `/component/virtuemart/25-` соответственно) - не работает, попробовал через .htaccess  таким образом: `Redirect 301 /component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=9 /component/virtuemart/25-` , тоже не работает, затем попытался в том же .htaccess прописать вот такую конструкцию

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://kover.mnogomesta.ru/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=9
RewriteRule (.*) http://kover.mnogomesta.ru/component/virtuemart/25-/$1 [R=301,L]
```

и тоже ничего не выходит, сайт успешно открывается по ссылке `/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=9` и никаких редиректов не происходит.

Подскажите, что можно сделать? P.S. редирект на сайте проверял `Redirect 301 /page1.html http://kover.mnogomesta.ru/page2.html` - всё работает, не пашет, только когда пытаешься средиректить с внешней ссылки.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ох что я могу сказать. Читайте про RewriteRule больше. Кратко - HTTP_HOST - это хост (kover.mnogomesta.ru) и он не может содержать `http://kover.mnogomesta.ru/component/virtuemart/?page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=9`.

Если вам только для SEO - эти ссылки надо удалить (чтоб джумла их не кушала), а в .htaccess прописать что-то подобное

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*manufacturer_id=.*$
RewriteRule ^.*manufacturer_id=(\d+).*$ /component/virtuemart/25-/$1 [R=301,L]
```

ЗЫ: на j1.5+vmart ооочень затратно сделать нормальный фильтр чего угодно.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но всёравно не помогло, компонент virtuemart в частности тот файл который отвечает за формирование страницы с товарами просто считывает параметры из $_GET массива, обрабатывает их и выдаёт результат. Я удалил ссылки из меню джумлы, однако она всё равно "кушает их" и никак не хочет выполнять редирект. =(

Comment: Вы поиграйтесь с регулярками в .htaccess, я вполне мог накосячить) Поправил немного, мож так пойдет